# Create a hexagon made up of smaller hexagons. Unity, c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use 9 similar for loops to create such hexagon which is made up of smaller hexagons.

[image: image of resulting hexagon]

My question is
How do I replace 9 for loops with just 1 for loop? Any ideas, much appreciated.

Middle column

```
    (x=0,y=(-4;4)
    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 4; y > -5; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

First column right

```
    (x=1,y=(-3.5;3.5))
    for (float x = 0.75f; x < 1.75; x++)
        {
            for (float y = 3.5f; y > -4.5; y--)
            {
                Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x,y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,0.0f,90.0f));
            }
        }
```

Second column right

```
    (x=2,y=(-3;3))
    for (float x = 1.5f; x < 2.5f; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 3; y > -4; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

Third column right

```
    (x=3,y=(-2.5;2.5))
    for (float x = 2.25f; x < 3.25; x++)
    {
        for (float y = 2.5f; y > -3.5; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

Fourth column right

```
    (x=4,y=(-2;2))
    for (int x = 3; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 2; y > -3; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

First column left

```
    (x=-1,y=(-3.5;3.5))
    for (float x = -0.75f; x < 0.25; x++)
    {
        for (float y = 3.5f; y > -4.5; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

Second column left

```
    (x=-2,y=(-3;3))
    for (float x = -1.5f; x < -0.5f; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 3; y > -4; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

Third column left

```
    (x=-3,y=(-2.5;2.5))
    for (float x = -2.25f; x < -1.25; x++)
    {
        for (float y = 2.5f; y > -3.5; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

Fourth column left

```
    (x=-4,y=(-2;2))
    for (int x = -3; x < -2; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 2; y > -3; y--)
        {
            Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f));
        }
    }
```

And I need this:
One formula creates the whole hexagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f);

for (int x = -4; x <= 4; x++)
{
    float xPos = x * 0.75F;

    int nrOfYTiles = 9 - Math.Abs(x);
    int halfNrOfYTiles = nrOfYTiles / 2;

    float yOffset = 0.5F * Math.Abs(x % 2);

    for (int y = 0; y < nrOfYTiles; y++)
    {
        float yPos = y - halfNrOfYTiles + yOffset;
        Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(xPos, yPos), rot);
    }
}
```

A more generic solution is:

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f);

const int maxTilesX = 9;
const int halfMaxTilesX = 9 / 2;
const int maxTilesY = 9;

int xMin = -halfMaxTilesX;
int xMax = halfMaxTilesX + (maxTilesX % 2); // add one if nr of tiles is odd

const float tileSizeX = 0.75F;
const float tileSizeY = 1F;
const float halTileSizeY = tileSizeY * 0.5F;

for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++)
{
    float xPos = x * tileSizeX;

    int tilesY = maxTilesY - Math.Abs(x);
    int halfTilesY = tilesY / 2;

    int yMin = -halfTilesY;
    int yMax = halfTilesY + (tilesY % 2);

    float yOffset = halTileSizeY * Math.Abs(x % 2);

    for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++)
    {
        float yPos = (y * tileSizeY) + yOffset;
        Instantiate(cell, new Vector2(xPos, yPos), rot);
    }
}
```

Comment: @TimMarkin Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Comment: @TimMarkin If it's the correct answer, please accept it as such.